# What were the rules about night flights from LHR in the 80s?

Tags: aviation-history, airport-operations, flight-schedules, noise-reduction

I was just reading a question over on movies.SE: [How could Ryan land in New York in early morning?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65745/how-could-ryan-land-in-new-york-in-early-morning), and the accepted answer suggests that Jack Ryan's plane takes off from LHR at about 4am.

One of the comments on the accepted answer says:

> ...there are no mid-night commercial flights from any commercial airport (especially LHR) due to night-time noise restrictions...

But were there *at the time the film is set*?

The film is "The Hunt for Red October", which is apparently [set in 1984](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/64931/14-deep-facts-about-hunt-red-october).

So, I did some searching, and found the following:

1. Heathrow does still [allow a limited number](https://www.heathrow.com/company/local-community/noise/operations/night-flights) of night *landings*, but that takeoffs aren't allowed before 6am.
2. There were court cases in the 90s and early 2000s about the noise caused by night operations at LHR. See [this ECHR case from 2001](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1260/0957456011498948?journalCode=nvwa).
3. An [obituary for John Stewart](https://www.richmondandtwickenhamtimes.co.uk/news/538326.profile-john-stewart-hacan-still-fighting-on-despite-years-of-lost-battles/), an anti-noise campaigner, which mentions noise (but not night flights) in the 70s, and the narrowly-lost ECHR court case.
4. This [article about Dan Air](https://www.danairremembered.com/1980s.php), which talks about, in 1982, "...flights to Eilat in Israel. The late night flights, [...] departing from Gatwick". Obviously, that's Israel, not America, and Gatwick, not Heathrow, but it's the right era.

So, my question is this:

**During the mid-80s, were there scheduled night flights from Heathrow to the US East Coast, such that Jack Ryan could plausibly have caught one at about 4am, were he not fictional?**